# How to add a common button to all pages in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my WP7 application, each page should have a Search button at the top. When pressing it, it should open the Search page.

How can this be done?  Is there a way to define the button in one place, or do I need to add the Search button to all pages?

Comment: What's with the downvotes? Isn't this a reasonable question? Sure you could copy and paste a search button into every single screen, but how would you do this without repeated code?

Comment: @Christopher..Thanks .. So much.. I asked this question because in android and iPhone we will do search button in main activity page. but in WP7?

Comment: While the question is legitimate (not that I have an answer), one thing to note is that all(?) WP7 phones have a physical Search button, so perhaps you could reconsider whether you really need a Search button in the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A global navigation control (which is what you are describing) does not fi within the standard design of an app conforming to the Metro principles. There are a couple of exceptions but as you're wanting do this because that's what you are also doing in the Android and iPhone versions of your app then I'd strongly recommend that you reconsider the design of the application so that it matches the stndards of other applications on the platform rather than your app on other platforms. Doing this will allow you to create an application which looks like it belongs on the platform and will behave as the user expects.

That said, there are 2 ways you could do this.

Firstly, you could add the button to the frame and wire up the event handler at application level.

Alternatively, you could create your own base class that inherits from ApplicationPage and contains the button you want everywhere. Each of the pages in your app should then inherit from your own base page.

I'd go for the second option as I usually find that I want my own base class for all pages for various pieces of functionality that I don't want to duplicate.